# What is signal 0 in a trap command?

Tags: bash, signals, trap

I'm following [this guide](http://mah.everybody.org/docs/ssh) on how to set up passwordless SSH authentication with ssh-agent.

To start up ssh-agent the author recommends the following code in `.bash_profile`:

```
SSHAGENT=/usr/bin/ssh-agent
SSHAGENTARGS="-s"
if [ -z "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" -a -x "$SSHAGENT" ]; then
    eval `$SSHAGENT $SSHAGENTARGS`
    trap "kill $SSH_AGENT_PID" 0
fi
```

I don't understand why it is trapping signal 0. According to [man 7 signal](http://linux.die.net/man/7/signal) there is no such signal.

Is this just a typo or bug or does this really achieve something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins):

```
trap [-lp] [[arg] sigspec ...]
```

> ... If a sigspec is EXIT (0) the command arg is executed on exit from the shell.

Comment: Correct. In case a reader came here because of the question's title, note that this is the meaning of `0` in a shell `trap` command. When sending a signal with `kill`, a signal number of 0 means not to send a signal after all; this is a way of testing the existence of the target process.

Comment: @Mat: Thanks a lot. I was reading [man 1 trap](http://linux.die.net/man/1/trap)...

Comment: But it's not in the list output by `trap -l`!

Comment: can you please address the case when the script is sourced?

Answer (score 2):

As @Mat shows in his answer, a SIGSPEC of 0, when used on the `trap` command will cause the `trap` command to run when the script exits.

This example illustrates what happens.

```
$ cat tr.bash 
#!/bin/bash

echo "PID: $$"

trap 'echo hi; exit 1' 0 1 2 15

while [ 1 ]; do
    sleep 3
done
```

When we run this:

```
$ ./tr.bash 
PID: 24086
```

It sits here waiting indefinitely. In another window if we now send `kill` signals to it you'll see that a `kill -0` will not kill the process, even though  signal 0 is listed in the `trap` command.

```
$ kill -0 $(pgrep tr.bash)
$
```

However if we `kill` the script using signal 1, `kill -1`:

```
$ kill -1 $(pgrep tr.bash)
$
```

We'll see that the script exits, and prints the message, "hi" 2 times. The first for signal 1, and the second because the script exited.

```
$ ./tr.bash 
PID: 24086
hi
hi
```

Answer (score 0):

trap on 0 is run when the shell exits.   It is commonly used to clean up tmp files in one place that is always executed:

> tmp=/tmp/myscript.$$
>
> trap 'rm -f $tmp; exit' 0 1 2 15
>
> do_a_bunch_of_stuff
>
> exit

the exit at the end of the trap exits the shell at the cleanup with the right status.