# What does kill -- -0 do?

Tags: linux, process, kill

Yes, I've seen that there's already a similar [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do), but I came across `kill -- -0` and was wondering what `--` is doing?

Comment: We do already have https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11376/ .

Comment: @JdeBP That post explains part of the question (the `--` part), but  doesn't explain `-0` though

Comment: Where did you run across this?  I've never seen it before, and am curious.  Thanks!

Comment: The question isn't asking about the `-0`.  Indeed, the question explicitly points to an existing question that covers that, too.

Comment: The question asks about signal zero (what is non-existent), and not about parametrization! **Not dupe!**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In UNIX/Linux world two dashes one after other mean end of options. For example if you want to search for string `-n` with `grep` you should use command like:

```
grep -- -n file
```

If you want to get only the line number in above case you should use

```
grep -l -- -n file
```

So the command `kill -- -0` try to send signal to process with ID `-0` (minus zero)

Comment: As for what process 0 is: "If *pid* equals 0, then *sig* is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process." ([`kill(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/kill.2.html))

Comment: Just for the record PID 0 is available in some UNIX OS (like Solaris)

Comment: As some system/kernel process, I hope? Though FWIW, [POSIX has almost the same description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/kill.html) of killing pid 0, except that it mentions unspecified system processes.

Comment: @ilkkachu: What would be a process group? Do you mean the Cgroup?
 Please be so kind an give an example where this use case occurs. Thanks.

Comment: @chevallier https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group

Comment: Why would one want to pass PID of _minus_ zero? Aren't integers on all CPUs running POSIX-compatible OSes today two's complement, thus lacking any special encoding for `-0`?

Comment: @ilkkachu  That seems to conflict with the answer here, unless I misread: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/169898/85039

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy I don't see the conflict - `-0` the option argument is signal specifier 0, aka no signal but process checking (that answer), and `-0` the non-option argument is the process group of the current process (this answer and ilkkachu's comment).

Comment: @muru according to that answer -0  "...will not actually in fact send anything to your process's PID, but will in fact check whether you have permissions to do so", but ilkkachu says it's for sending signal to every proc in process group.  So is it actually for sending or for checking ?

Comment: @SergiyKolodyazhnyy `-0` *the option* will not send anything. `-0` the *non-option* will. Hence the `--` in the command here.

Comment: @muru Ah, I see now !!! That makes more sense.

Answer (score 7):

In this case it is used to denote that the `-0` is not an option being passed in. If you were to do `kill -0` it would think of `-0` as an option not as the PID being passed in.

For example if you did `ls -- -l` it will look for a file named `-l` as opposed to just listing the directory in long form.