# Proxying localhost to HTTPS using socat returns Connection refused first time

Tags: bash, nginx, socat

I'm trying to fetch a page from `https://termbin.com/9hc2k` using bash redirections and `socat`, especially using special file `/dev/tcp/localhost/8080` to open a network connection.

```bash
# fetch.sh
# fetch uploaded text from termbin.com

url=$1

# check if url is provided as argument
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "error: provide url" >&2
    echo >&2
    echo "Usage: fetch.sh [url]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

n1=$'\r\n'
request=$(cat <<END
GET /${url}/ HTTP/1.1
Host: termbin.com
Connection: close
$n1 
$n1
END
)
#echo "$request"

socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr ssl:termbin.com:443,verify=0 &
socat_pid=$!
exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080
echo "$request" >&3
cat <&3

exec 3>&-
```

If I try to fetch `https://termbin.com/9hc2k`:

```
$ ./fetch.sh 9hc2k
./fetch.sh: connect: Connection refused
./fetch.sh: line 26: /dev/tcp/localhost/8080: Connection refused
./fetch.sh: line 27: 3: Bad file descriptor
./fetch.sh: line 28: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

First time I get Connection refused error.

If I try again however,

```
$ ./fetch.sh 9hc2k
2022/07/30 12:29:18 socat[497218] E bind(5, {AF=2 0.0.0.0:8080}, 16): Address already in use
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Sat, 30 Jul 2022 02:29:20 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 6
Last-Modified: Sat, 30 Jul 2022 01:51:42 GMT
Connection: close
ETag: "62e48eae-6"
Accept-Ranges: bytes

hello
```

As you can see the second time of trying it works. I have fetched text `hello` from the link.

I don't know why it fails the first time and then second time (and subsequent) around it works. Can you tell me why this is so and what is the most rational fix? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Kamil for your explanation. I ended up fixing it by monitoring the status of the socat pid to become 'S'.

Here's my fixed code.

```
# fetch uploaded text from termbin.com

url=$1

# check if url is provided as argument
if [[ $# -lt 1 ]]; then
    echo "error: provide url" >&2
    echo >&2
    echo "Usage: fetch.sh [url]" >&2
    exit 1
fi

n1=$'\r\n'
request=$(cat <<END
GET /${url}/ HTTP/1.1
Host: termbin.com
Connection: close
$n1 
$n1
END
)
#echo "$request"

socat TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr ssl:termbin.com:443,verify=0 &
socat_pid=$!

# loop until socat's pid status becomes 'S'
while [[ -z $(ps -p $socat_pid -o stat --no-headers | grep 'S') ]]; do
    :
done

exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080
echo "$request" >&3
cat <&3

# if socat's pid status is 'S' then kill it
if [[ -n $(ps -p $socat_pid -o stat --no-headers | grep 'S') ]]; then
    kill -9 $socat_pid
fi

exec 3>&-
```

Answer (score 2):

My guess is `exec 3<>/dev/tcp/localhost/8080` happens *too soon* after `socat … &` and at this time `socat` is not ready yet.

Your script does not kill the `socat` it spawned. When you try again, the old `socat` is already there and able to handle a new connection.

A quick and dirty fix is to `sleep 1` or so before `exec 3<>…`. A better fix is to try and periodically retry `exec 3<>…` until it succeeds or the number of tries reaches some sane threshold (then you assume failure) or [`kill -s 0 "$socat_pid"`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/169970/108618) fails (then you know `socat` has exited for whatever reason).