# What is the meaning of `kill -0 <pid>`?

Tags: process, signals

I found in a script a call to `kill -0 <pid>`.

It looks like a way to check if process  exists.

I don't know the exact meaning of `kill -0` so I looked for its
definition but I didn't find any information.

`man signal`, on many different flavour of unix, don't mention a signal 0.

`kill -l 0` returns a T (that should be a SIGT).

So what is the meaning of `kill 0 <pid>` ?

Comment: As someone pointed out to me my question is a duplicate of [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169898/what-does-kill-0-do). Before asking I did a search for kill -0 but I wasn't able to find the above question (and answers). Now I see that I have to search for "kill -0" (with quotes) to find it. I realize that, from an IT point of view, the search for such a string is problematic. This being the case, finding the answer is not immediate. In any case thanks for the support and I think this question can be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

From the man page for `kill` (`man kill`)

> If sig is 0, then no signal is sent, but error checking is still performed.

so you're correct that it is a way to determine if a process exists

Comment: I found what you wrote on centos man page. I was not able to find any reference to signal 0 on Ubuntu or raspberry man pages!
Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Comment: @karlacio "I was not able to find …" – It looks `man 1 kill` in Ubuntu misses this, but it tells you to "see also" `kill(2)`. Some commands are interfaces to system calls; when `man 1 foo` tells you to see `foo(2)`, it may be the case. So you invoke `man 2 kill` and the information should be there. Such digging is not very intuitive, I agree `man 1 kill` should cover what you asked. In general "see also" in manual pages lets you discover interesting commands and concepts. And there is [`info`](https://askubuntu.com/q/9325/693277). I think `info kill` in Ubuntu answers your question.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski you are right, I completely agree with you.