# Automatically running code before closing SSH connection

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm remotely connecting to a shared server and I would like to have a line of code executed automatically in the remote machine **before** I close the connection (e.g. by pressing Ctrl+D).

More specifically, I'd like to kill the SSH agent before I leave, as I noticed it keeps running even after I'm gone. The agent is started by another program, so I thought it'd be easier to just kill it before I leave rather than changing how it is started.

Is it possible to automatically run an arbitrary command -- like the one below -- **before** closing an SSH connection?

```bsh
# user attempts to close connection

# an arbitrary code or script runs
eval "$(ssh-agent -k)"

# connection is closed
```

Perhaps something similar to the `-t` flag (`ssh -t user@domain.com 'cd /some/path; bash -l'`), but that runs before disconnecting rather than after connecting.

Comment: Which shell do you use (on remote)?

Comment: @ibuprofen I use `bash` both locally and on remote

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set a `trap` in `.bashrc` that runs when [shell exits](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/17314/140633):

Something like

```bsh
trap 'test -n "$SSH_AGENT_PID" && eval "$(/usr/bin/ssh-agent -k)"' 0
```

Optionally add a routine in `.bash_logout`

Comment: Great, I wasn't even aware of `.bash_logout`. Any of these two options work for me, thanks!

Comment: @TheMechanic Yes. It is neatly "hidden" under "Bash Startup Files" https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files